# Pasar mas de una consulta en un solo array

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Hola a todos buenas tardes, estoy tratando de mostrar resultados en una tabla mediante un filtro de dos select (es decir, selecciono valores de dos select y mediante un boton envio las variables al controlador que tiene una funcion procesada via ajax para hacer la busqueda de datos segun estos parametros) pero el problema que presento es que los datos a mostrar son de ambas tablas, por lo cual en mi controlador tengo mas de una consulta que necesitaria enviar al ajax para que pinte la tabla, con una sola consulta y retornando una sola variable me funciona bien, hago el filtro en la vista y me pinta la tabla, pero no se como unir la segunda y una posible tercer o cuarta consulta (todas estas consultas se filtran por las mismas 2 variables enviadas por el ajax)

fijense que uniendo ambas variables en una sala variable, y retornando esa variable, por consola me llega la informacion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi controlador:

```
public function getFiltro($bodega_id, $servicio_id){

        /*INGRESOS, TRANSFERENCIAS para bodegas fisicas*/

        /* transferecnias, asignaciones PARA BODEGAS MOVILES*/

        //ingresos
        $ingresos = DB::table('det_ingreso_materials as d')
        ->join('ingreso_materials as a', 'a.id', 'd.ingreso_material_id')
        ->join('servicios as s', 's.id', 'a.servicio_id')
        ->join('materials as m', 'm.id', 'd.material_id')
        ->select('a.id', 'd.cantidad', 'd.bodega_id', 'm.nombre_producto', 'm.sku', 's.servicio')
        ->where('d.bodega_id', $bodega_id)
        ->where('s.id', $servicio_id)
        ->get();

        $trasnferencias_fisicas = DB::table('det_transferencia_bodegas as d')
        ->join('transferencia_bodegas as t', 't.id', 'd.transferencia_bodega_id')
        ->join('servicios as s', 's.id', 't.servicio_id')
        ->join('materials as m', 'm.id', 'd.material_id')
        ->select('t.id', 'd.cantidad', 'm.nombre_producto', 'm.sku', 's.servicio')
        ->where('d.destino_bodega_id', $bodega_id)
        ->where('s.id', $servicio_id)
        ->get();

        $array = [$ingresos, $trasnferencias_fisicas];

        //return $array;
        return json_encode($array);
    }
```

y este es el ajax que estoy manejando ahora:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filtrar').click(function(){
            var bodega_id = $('#bodega_id').val();
            var servicio_id = $('#servicio_id').val();
            //$('#bodega').show();
            if (bodega_id != '' && servicio_id != '') {
                //$('#inventario').DataTable().destroy();
                filtro_tablas(bodega_id, servicio_id);

            }else{
                alert('Seleccione Bodega y Servicio a Mostrar');
                //$('#bodega').hide();
            }
        });

        function filtro_moviles(){

        }

        function filtro_tablas(){
            var bodega_id = $('select[name=bodega_id]').val();
            var servicio_id = $('select[name=servicio_id]').val();
            //$('#id_bodega').val('');
            //$('#id_servicio').val(servicio_id);
            $("#cuerpo").html("");
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('/inventarios/bodegas') }}"+`/${bodega_id}`+`/${servicio_id}`,
                method:"get",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                        var tr = `<tr>
                        <td>`+data[i].id+`</td>
                        <td>`+data[i].sku+`</td>
                        <td>`+data[i].nombre_producto+`</td>
                        <td>`+data[i].cantidad+`</td>
                        </tr>`;
                        $("#saldo_bodegas").append(tr);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //CARGAR INFO DE LA BODEGA AL SELECCIONAR DESDE SELECT
        $('#bodega_id').on('change', function(){
            var bodega_id = $('select[name=bodega_id]').val();
            //$('#tecnico_id').val('');
            //$('#tecnico_id').val(id);
            $("#cuerpo").html("");
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('inventario/bodega/info') }}"+`/${bodega_id}`,
                method:"get",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(info){
                    //console.log(info);
                    for(var i=0; i < info.length; i++){
                        $('label#razon_social').text(info[i].razon_social);
                        $('label#nombre_bodega').text(info[i].nombre_bodega);
                        $('label#direccion').text(info[i].direccion);
                        $('label#ciudad').text(info[i].ciudad);
                        $('label#region').text(info[i].region);
                        $('label#responsable').text(info[i].responsable);
                        $('label#rut').text(info[i].rut);
                    }
                }
            });
         });


});
</script>
```

Tal vez estoy bien pero no se como pintar la informacion de ambas variables, ya que solo me muestra como UNDEFINED en las celdas de la tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El array que devuelves tiene dos niveles de profundidad.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ... }
```

Ahí estás recorriendo el primer nivel. Necesitas un segundo bucle para alcanzar donde están los objetos/items.

Por lo tanto cuando haces:

```
<td>+data[i].id+</td>
```

`data[i]` es un array, no un objeto, por lo que no tiene la propiedad id y por eso te devuelve `undefined`.